C# PDF Reader for Tabular format complex PDF .NET 9 API
I am using the PdfPig library to read tabular data from a PDF. While processing, I am encountering issues where the extracted values appear randomly, and some values are swapped or misaligned. I am unsure how to resolve this problem effectively.
Objective:
I need to extract the tabular data in a structured format, ensuring that multi-row content within a single column is captured correctly and the positional order remains intact.
I have attached the PDF for reference, along with the output I am currently getting.
Issue:
Data from multi-row cells in a single column is not read in proper order.
Positional alignment and sequence of values are inconsistent.
Could you please guide me on how to accurately extract the tabular data while preserving the correct structure and order? Your insights would be greatly appreciated!
Current Output:
4 | 0459270 | **Saif | Azim | Khan** | M&E_MST | 01-12-2021 | 100973591911 | NA | 30.00 | 27.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | M | 11632 | 3068 | 6869 | 2455 | 2000 | 26024 | 10469 | 2761 | 6182 | 2210 | 1800 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 23422 | 0 | 23422 | 1800 | 0 | 200 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 30 | 2030 | 21392 l | a | 2361040425 e **RICIAN** | 6912158 3 | 0459269 | **Vijay | Namdeo | Kharat** | 01-12-2021 | 100619445298 | NA | 30.00 | 30.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | M | 11632 | 3068 | 6869 | 600 | 0 | 22169 | 11632 | 3068 | 6869 | 600 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 22169 | 0 | 22169 | 1800 | 0 | 200 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 30 | 2030 | 20139 **M&E_ELECT** | l | a | 0000006011 e **Salunkhe** | 01162 2 | 0459262 | M&E_HVAC | 01-12-2021 | 101167974412 | NA | 30.00 | 30.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | M | 11632 | 3068 | 6362 | 0 | 1788 | 22850 | 11632 | 3068 | 6362 | 0 | 1788 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 22850 | 0 | 22850 | 1800 | 0 | 200 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 30 | 2030 | 20820 **Ganesh | Sampat** | l | a | 0651001000 e 8999 1 | 0459259 |** Mohd | Akram** | M&E_HVAC | 01-12-2021 | 101621135920 | NA | 30.00 | 30.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | M | 11632 | 3068 | 6869 | 0 | 2281 | 23850 | 11632 | 3068 | 6869 | 0 | 2281 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 23850 | 0 | 23850 | 1800 | 0 | 200 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 30 | 2030 | 21820 l | a | 0421010001
Code:
public class PdfDataExtractor
{
    public List<List<string>> ExtractData(Stream stream)
    {
        var rows = new List<List<string>>();

        using (var document = PdfDocument.Open(stream))
        {
            for (int pageIndex = 0; pageIndex < document.NumberOfPages; pageIndex++)
            {
                var page = document.GetPage(pageIndex + 1);

                // Get words on the page
                var words = page.GetWords();

                // Group words into rows
                var groupedRows = GroupWordsIntoRows(words);

                // Add grouped rows to the result
                rows.AddRange(groupedRows);
            }
        }

        return rows;
    }

    private List<List<string>> GroupWordsIntoRows(IEnumerable<Word> words)
    {
        var rows = new List<List<string>>();
        var currentRow = new List<(double x, string text)>();
        double? currentY = null;

        foreach (var word in words.OrderBy(w => w.BoundingBox.Bottom).ThenBy(w => w.BoundingBox.Left))
        {
            // Start a new row if the vertical position changes significantly
            if (currentY.HasValue && Math.Abs(currentY.Value - word.BoundingBox.Bottom) > 5)
            {
                // Finalize the current row and start a new one
                rows.Add(currentRow.OrderBy(w => w.x).Select(w => w.text).ToList());
                currentRow = new List<(double x, string text)>();
            }

            // Add the word to the current row
            currentRow.Add((word.BoundingBox.Left, word.Text));
            currentY = word.BoundingBox.Bottom;
        }

        // Add the last row
        if (currentRow.Any())
        {
            rows.Add(currentRow.OrderBy(w => w.x).Select(w => w.text).ToList());
        }

        return rows;
    }
}

here I am attaching PDF screenshot

I have docs https://github.com/UglyToad/PdfPig/wiki but not able to find any solution
